# Akka actor backpressure / flow control

Tags: akka

Suppose I have a RoundRobinPool router of five actors, and a list of 100,000 work items I need to have these actors process.

```
val myrouter: ActorRef =
  context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[Worker]), "myrouter")

for (a <- mylist)
  myrouter ! a
```

What is the proper way of implementing flow control so my actors don't get overwhelmed? Is there a concept of backpressure, like in akka-http? Is there something I can check which tells me that all my actors are busy, so I can pause my loop until they catch up?

Comment: You can look into the Work Pulling pattern.  You can also use Akka Streams (with the `Source` being your list of work) and ask (via `mapAsync`) to get back-pressure incorporated into your work handling.

Comment: Thank you, Work Pulling pattern looks interesting. I know Akka-streams would also solve the problem, but it's too much of a disruptive change for my current code base.